# How can i redirect links have better look with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I use this but it not works in double "GET" variables:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^about.html$ index.php?do=about [L]
RewriteRule ^blogs.html$ index.php?do=blogs [L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/(.*).html$ index.php?do=blog&seo=$1 [L]
```

---

```
example.com/?do=blog&seo=what-is-sass
```

to

```
example.com/blogs/what-is-sass
```

EDIT: My index.php works like OnePage app

```
<?php
$do=$_GET['do'];
if(file_exists("components/".$do.".php")){
    require_once("components/".$do.".php");
}else{
    include("main.php");
}
?>
```

I want to do all processes in my index.php

index.php looking for "is any folder exists here ?" if is not includes do.php

if exists it gets do and require in my index.php

Comment: What do you mean "not works" exactly? The directive you posted does the opposite of what you've stated... it would rewrite a URL of the form `/blogs/what-is-sass.html` (note the `.html` extension) to `/index.php?do=blog&seo=what-is-sass`. Assuming you have no other directives in your `.htaccess` file and this `.htaccess` is located in the document root. (?)

Comment: My index.php works like one page app. `<?php
$do=$_GET['do'];
if(file_exists("components/".$do.".php")){
 require_once("components/".$do.".php");
}else{
 include("main.php");
}
?>`  i want to do all procesess in my index.php.

Comment: Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Yes i got to many of them for all my pages.

Comment: In isolation, there's nothing particularly wrong with the rule you posted (note the `.html` extension - as mentioned), so you may have a conflict with existing directives. Please add the contents of your `.htaccess` file to your question.

Comment: So, by "not works", you mean the `seo` URL parameter is not being passed to your script?

Comment: It works but my direction going to /blogs(it is not exists) file in my dictionary. If i want to go back to home page, it seems like  this `blogs/what-is-sass/index` or `blogs/index`. My home page link is <a href="index">.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works but my direction going to /blogs(it is not exists) file in my dictionary. If i want to go back to home page, it seems like this blogs/what-is-sass/index or blogs/index. My home page link is `<a href="index">`.

The problem is not with your `.htaccess` directives but with your *relative* internal links. The relative link is naturally resolved - by the browser (client-side) - relative to the current URL. If you link to `index` when at the URL `/blogs/what-is-sass`, then the browser will resolve this as `/blogs/what-is-sass/index`.

You need to use either root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute URLs in your HTML source. For example:

```
<a href="/index">
```

See this question on the Webmasters Stack for more information:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L]
> RewriteRule ^about.html$ index.php?do=about [L]
> RewriteRule ^blogs.html$ index.php?do=blogs [L]
> RewriteRule ^blogs/(.*).html$ index.php?do=blog&seo=$1 [L]
> ```

Note that `RewriteCond` (condition) directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows. However, if none of these requests (ie. `/index.html`, `/about.html`, `/blogs.html` or `/blogs/<something>.html`) map to physical files then these two conditions are superfluous and can simply be removed.

Also, you've used `/blogs/what-is-sass` as an example URL throughout your question and in comments, but the directive above would only match a URL of the form `/blogs/what-is-sass.html`, *with* a `.html` extension. (?)

Comment: This is great explanation of an answer, thank you for sharing the same cheers.